# Check if Tomcat is running via shell script

Tags: shell, tomcat

I need to check if Tomcat is running in my system via a shell script. If not I need to catch the process id and kill Tomcat. How shall it be achieved?

Comment: Define "is running". By the ordinary definition, something that is not running does not have a process ID, and can't be killed. I am not just being snarky here; you presumably mean "is handling requests properly", and once you can define that, you'll know how to write your script. (Also, you may want to try Serverfault, they have a lot more experience with system monitoring)

Comment: @BugFinder: I have tried using this command, 
pid=$(ps -fe | grep tomcat). This would get all the process with context 'tomcat'. then used killall.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in order to get the running process, I've used this command:

`ps x | grep [full_path_to_tomcat] | grep -v grep | cut -d ' ' -f 1`

You have to be careful, though. It works on my setup, but it may not run everywhere... I have two installations of tomcat, one is /usr/local/tomcat on port 8080 and /usr/local/tomcat_8081 on port 8081. I have to use '/usr/local/tomcat/' (with the final slash) as the full_path because otherwise it would return 2 different pids if tomcat_8081 is running as well.

Here's the explanation of what this command does:

1) `ps x` gives you a list of running processes ordered by pid, tty, stat, time running and command.

2) Applying `grep [full_path_to_tomcat]` to it will find the pattern [full_path_to_tomcat] within that list. For instance, running `ps x | grep /usr/local/tomcat/` might get you the following:

```
13277 ?        Sl     7:13 /usr/local/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.fil
e=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties [...] -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomca
t [...]
21149 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep /usr/local/tomcat/
```

3) As we get 2 entries instead of one due to the `grep /usr/local/tomcat/` matching the pattern, let's remove it. `-v` is the invert-match flag for grep, meaning it will select only lines that do not match the pattern. So, in the previous example, using `ps -x | grep /usr/local/tomcat/ | grep -v grep` will return:

```
13277 ?        Sl     7:13 /usr/local/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.fil
e=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties [...] -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomca
t [...]
```

4) Cool, now we have the pid we need. Still, we need to strip all the rest. In order to do that, let's use `cut`. This command removes sections from a FILE or a standard output. The -d option is the delimiter and the -f is the field you need. Great. So we can use a space (' ') as a delimiter, and get the first field, which corresponds to the pid. Running `ps x | grep /usr/local/tomcat/ | grep -v grep | cut -d ' ' -f 1` will return:

```
13277
```

Which is what you need. To use it in your script, it's simple:

```
#replace below with your tomcat path
tomcat_path=/users/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.30
pid=$(ps x | grep "${tomcat_path}" | grep -v grep | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
if [ "${pid}" ]; then
  eval "kill ${pid}"
fi
```

Comment: Verbose and good answer. Only thing I would do different is using `awk` instead of `cut`, like so:
`ps axuw | grep path/to/tomcat | grep -v grep |  awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: To me is not working... my tomcat is up, I can see the pid by "ps -ef | grep tomcat", but this command above return nothing

Comment: @WilliansMartins did you replace tomcat_path with your actual path? If you have only one tomcat installation you could just use `grep tomcat` instead.

Comment: If found, it prints a blank line, got it working using @atripes solution. If no tomcat is running, it prints nothing. Using Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: When the process number is below 10000, 'ps x' put leading space characters and 'cut -d ' ' -f 1' returns empty. It's better use atripes' solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898686/check-if-tomcat-is-running-via-shell-script/16024189#comment29851986_16024189

Answer (score 4):

One way to check by using wget for your server address and checking the status.

Check this link here :

http://www.velvettools.com/2013/07/shell-script-to-check-tomcat-status-and.html#.VX_jfVz-X1E

```sh
TOMCAT_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat-folder/

is_Running ()
{

        wget -O - http://yourserver.com/ >& /dev/null
 if( test $? -eq 0 ) then
  return 0
 else
  return 1
 fi
}



stop_Tomcat ()
{
 echo "shutting down......"
 $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
}

start_Tomcat ()
{
 echo "starting......"
 $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/startup.sh
}

restart ()
{
 stop_Tomcat
 sleep 10
 kill_Hanged_Processes
 start_Tomcat
 sleep 60
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 2):

the easy way to do that is :

```
 ps -ef | grep tomcat
```

by using this command you'll get :

```
user [id-to-kill] Date [tomcat-path]
```

last step is killing the process

```
sudo kill -9 [id-to-kill]
```

Congratulation, your process was killed lOol

Comment: It shows process even tomcat is not running. `1000      8309  4960  0 20:51 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto tomcat` or, if you search for anything that doesn't exist(`neo44`), it replies back `$ ps aux | grep neo44
1000      8397  0.0  0.0  13640   952 pts/1    S+   20:53   0:00 grep --color=auto neo44`

Comment: `ps -ef | grep tomcat` will find anything in the output that has "tomcat", often including the `grep tomcat` process.  you can filter it using the -v flag like so, `ps -ef | grep tomcat | grep -v grep`, use `pgrep`, or something more distro and setup-specific, like `service tomcat status`.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat's default port is 8080. u can grep it and use port status in comparision loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
STAT=`netstat -na | grep 8080 | awk '{print $7}'`
if [ "$STAT" = "LISTEN" ]; then
    echo "DEFAULT TOMCAT PORT IS LISTENING, SO ITS OK"
elif [ "$STAT" = "" ]; then 
    echo "8080 PORT IS NOT IN USE SO TOMCAT IS NOT WORKING"
    ## only if you defined CATALINA_HOME in JAVA ENV ##
    cd $CATALINA_HOME/bin
    ./startup.sh
fi
RESULT=`netstat -na | grep 8080 | awk '{print $7}' | wc -l`
if [ "$RESULT" = 0 ]; then
    echo "TOMCAT PORT STILL NOT LISTENING"
elif [ "$RESULT" != 0 ]; then
    echo "TOMCAT PORT IS LISTENINS AND SO TOMCAT WORKING"
fi
```

this way you can compare the script.you grep port 8080 if you are using the default port for tomcat.this will only check whether tomcat is running.
then you can check the processes using the port
lsof -i:8080    //if using port 8080

the if you want to free the port by killing the process using it use this command
kill 75782  //if for instance 75782 is the process using the port

Comment: I've edited your post to fix the code formatting. For future reference, the { } button will mark the selection as code (by inserting 4 spaces at the front of each line).

Comment: @gopinagh: To be clear, this is dansh's solution, not mine. Glad to hear it worked, though.

Comment: this script doesn't work for other languages. On my system, which is in pt_br, I had to use awk '{print $6}', which give me "OUÇA" (the equivalent of "LISTEN"

Comment: I use an EnglishUS setup and also had to change to {print $6} .